# Compiler error with is_permutation and predicate for struct

Tags: c++, algorithm, struct, compiler-errors, predicate

I don't understand the compiler error I'm getting in the last line of:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>


struct X{
  int number;
};
bool same_number_X(const int & a, const X & b)
{ return a == b.number; }


bool same_number_int(const int & a, const int & b)
{ return a == b; }


int main(){

   std::vector<int> vec1{1,2,3};
   std::vector<int> vec2{2,3,1};
   std::vector<X> vec3{{2},{3},{1}};

   std::cout << std::is_permutation(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), vec2.begin(), same_number_int);
   std::cout << std::is_permutation(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), vec3.begin(), same_number_X);
}
```

You can see the error [HERE](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1ncIoI%240)
It says

```
In instantiation of 'typename std::iterator_traits<_InputIterator>::difference_type std::count_if(_IIter, _IIter, _Predicate) [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<X*, std::vector<X> >; _Predicate = std::_Bind<bool (*(std::_Placeholder<1>, int))(const int&, const X&)>; typename std::iterator_traits<_InputIterator>::difference_type = long int]':
c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:4367:37: required from 'bool std::is_permutation(_FIter1, _FIter1, _FIter2, _BinaryPredicate) [with _FIter1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _FIter2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<X*, std::vector<X> >; _BinaryPredicate = bool (*)(const int&, const X&)]'
source.cpp:23:90: required from here
c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:4681:2: error: no match for call to '(std::_Bind<bool (*(std::_Placeholder<1>, int))(const int&, const X&)>) (X&)'
```

Can anybody explain/solve it in non-compiler words? :-)

Comment: adding an `operator int() const` fixed the issue for me (using the `(int, int)` comparator. I imagine an implicit int construct would do the same for an `(X,X)` comparator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Paragraph 25.2.12/1 of the C++11 Standard:

```
template<class ForwardIterator1, class ForwardIterator2>
bool is_permutation(ForwardIterator1 first1, ForwardIterator1 last1,
                    ForwardIterator2 first2);

template<class ForwardIterator1, class ForwardIterator2, class BinaryPredicate>
bool is_permutation(ForwardIterator1 first1, ForwardIterator1 last1,
                    ForwardIterator2 first2, BinaryPredicate pred);
```

> 1 *Requires*: `ForwardIterator1` and `ForwardIterator2` **shall have the same value type**. The comparison
>   function shall be an equivalence relation.

In your last call to `is_permutation()`, the first argument (from which type `ForwardIterator1` is deduced) is an iterator of `int` values, while the third argument (from which type `ForwardIterator2` is deduced) is an iterator of `X` values. You are therefore violating the pre-conditions stated by the above paragraph.

Comment: Hmm, I don't quite understand the difference between 'type' and 'value type' : `ForwardIterator1` and `ForwardIterator2` are different types, right? but they need to point to the same value?

Comment: The *value type* of an iterator is the type of the value you get when you dereference the iterator. The *type* of the iterator (like of any other objet) is the type of the iterator object itself. In general, you can obtain the value type of an iterator as `typename iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type`, where `Iterator` is the type of the iterator.

Comment: @user2081073: `ForwardIterator1` and `ForwardIterator2` *could* be different types (e.g. iterator obtained from a `list<int>` vs iterator obtained from a `vector<int>`), but they need to be iterators of the same value type (i.e. both iterators of `int`)

Comment: Well, ok - I still don't get why that precondition is needed when there are still at most N² comparisons in the worst case. (and std::equal doesn't seem to have that precondition..) But that's definitely the answer. Thanks Andy!

Comment: Ohh. We need that precondition to handle duplicates in the input ranges, e.g. to see that (1,1,2) and (1,2,2) are not permutations of each other.. Lesson learned...